# Debugging JS in CRM 2011 Outlook Client

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking for a way to debug the Microsoft CRM 2011 Outlook client. We are having an issue on one of our functions that is only happening in the outlook client, and I would like to be able to gather some information as to what is going on but am unable to due to having no way to debug the CRM client.

Has anybody ever found a way to do this? Is there a way to attach Visual Studio or IE to a different application to debug JS using that? I mean I can throw alerts constantly and just see where it gets to, but that's not clean or effective.

Comment: alert alert and alert :)

Comment: It's really frustrating that there is no other way for this

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with debugger?  My attempts to use debugger; will prompt me to launch visual studio, but the code won't actually load in visual studio.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have that issue, wish I could help!

Comment: @GuidoPreite alert is most useful if you can pause execution in an active debugger - the `debugger;` statement is better suited here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I discovered that it can indeed be done. Since the far reaches of the internet did not seem to have much I'll put it here

I have visual studio installed, so prior to the line where the error occured, I added:

`debugger;`

This prompted me to select which tool I would like to use to debug the JS, and I selected visual studio 2010, and this allowed me to step through as I had hoped

You ALSO have to un-check Disable script debugging (Other) ([Instructions here](http://www.mayanksrivastava.com/2010/02/debugging-java-script-in-visual-studio.html))